# Python Merge Key by having condition ( Ranges ) in 2 DataFrames using python

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I would like to merge (using how = 'left') whereas dataframe_A is on the left and data_frame_B is on the right. The Column/index level names to join on are "name","weight" and money". The height and weight difference is allow up to 2 cm. 

I am not using for loop as my dataset is too big, it will take 2 days to complete

E.g.

> INPUT
>
> > dataframe_A name:John, height: 170, weight :70
> >     
> >     dataframe_B name:John, height 172, weight :69

OUTPUT

> output_dataframe : name:John,height: 170, weight :70, money:100, grade :1

I have two dataframe :

```
dataframe_A = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['John', 'May', 'Jane', 'Sally'],
                            'height': [170, 180, 160, 155],
                            'weight': [70, 88, 60, 65],
                            'money': [100, 1120, 2000, 3000]})

dataframe_B = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['John', 'May', 'Jane', 'Sally'],
                            'height': [172, 180, 160, 155],
                            'weight': [69, 88, 60, 65],
                            'grade': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
```

In selecting statment should be,

```
    SELECT * FROM dataframe_A LEFT JOIN dataframe_B 
ON dataframe_A.name= dataframe_B.name and 
dataframe_A.height => dataframe_B.height+2 or
dataframe_A.height <= dataframe_B.height-2 and
dataframe_A.weight=> dataframe_B.weight+2 or
dataframe_A.weight<= dataframe_B.weight-2 
;
```

But I am unsure how to put it in python as i am still learning

```
output_dataframe =pd.merge(dataframe_A,dataframe_B,how='left',on=['name','height','weight'] + ***the range condition***
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) first and then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
df = pd.merge(dataframe_A, dataframe_B, on='name', how='left', suffixes=('','_'))
m1 = df['height'].between(df['height_'] - 2, df['height_'] + 2)
m2 = df['weight'].between(df['weight_'] - 2, df['weight_'] + 2)

df = df.loc[m1 & m2, dataframe_A.columns.tolist() + ['grade']]
print (df)
    name  height  weight  money  grade
0   John     170      70    100      1
1    May     180      88   1120      2
2   Jane     160      60   2000      3
3  Sally     155      65   3000      4
```